# Creating a persistent store which is a subset of a Core Data store

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am developing a project that might be thought of a "meta-app" in that it has a UI which creates the data structures that would be used by several simpler apps. Each of these latter apps would use a proper subset of the data created by the parent app (the xcdatamodel for each, however, would remain unchanged).

My question is what reasonably efficient strategies have others used to create persistent stores which hold a subset of a data in the generating Core Data store?

Comment: Is the data separated out by entity, or would objects of all entity types be present in all persistent stores?

Comment: @jrturton Thx for clarifying q: objects of all entity types would be present in all persistent stores;   (null values are built into the model to anticipate non-usage of some entities)

Comment: So one app is not for release, just to create the seed data for a set of other apps that will be released?

Comment: @wain : yup, that's the basic idea.

Comment: Something like this? http://mubaloo.com/news-info/making-a-metaapp-helper-mac-apps-for-ios-developers

Comment: @jrturton: have upmarked your comment Richard for its link to your useful article. Have stayed entirely within iOS thus far, so adding a OS X Cocoa application target is all new to me. Your last para "they are great for simple use cases as described here, but can very quickly turn nasty if you try to do anything involved with them, and are very difficult to debug" worries me - my model has around 25 entity types linked by about 40 relationships; would that qualify as too "involved"?

Comment: That refers to bindings themselves rather than the complexity of the model. If you're just updating fields in a database, no problem. It's if you try and involve complex rules or validation that they can go wrong.